# Cassandra 1.1 - Setup for 24GB RAM and Row Cache

Tags: cassandra

I would like to tune Cassandra for heavy read scenario with skinny rows (5-50 columns). The idea is to use row cache, and enable key cache just in case - when data is to large for row cache.

I have dual Intel Xeon server with 24GB RAM (3 in ring, two data centers - gives 6 machines in total)

Those are changes that I've made to default configuration:

*cassandra-env.sh*

```
#JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -ea"
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="6G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="500M"
```

*cassandra.yaml*

```
# do not persist caches to disk
key_cache_save_period: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0

key_cache_size_in_mb: 512
row_cache_size_in_mb: 14336 
row_cache_provider: SerializingCacheProvider
```

The idea it to dedicate 6GB to Cassandra JVM, 0.5GB to key cache (out of 6GB heap), and 14GB to row cache as off-heap.
OS has still 4GB which should be enough, since there is running only one JVM process and it should have overhead of max 2GB.

Is this setup optimal? Any hints?

Thanks,
Maciej

Comment: The columns are read in a independent way or you always read all columns of a row ?

Comment: Then, maybe you can serialize your data to a single column (if no index is involved) you will reduce the number of columns, saving space and cpu power.

Comment: @MaciejMiklas Is there key cache out of heap?

Comment: No - it's not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using 1.1.6 version. 
SerializingCacheProvider will save cache data at Native Heap area. 
That area is not for GC inspect. so It will not be occurred GC.
Your row_cache_size_in_mb setting is for SerializingCache's reference object.
That reference is saved using FreeableMemory(It is in 1.1.x. but after 1.2, it changed).
In other words, Your real cache value is not calculated when calculating row_cache_size_in_mb.

At the result If you want to calculate row_cache_size_in_mb, try to set from minimal size.
In my case, when I set 500mb, each node was using 2G old gen.(in according to deal which data set)

Answer (score 1):

Run the [heapspace_calculator](https://github.com/joaquincasares/heap-calculator) and use the suggested value as an initial heap configuration. Monitor your heap usage with "nodetool info".

Try to use short column names and merge columns when possible.

Answer (score 1):

This setup works just fine - I've tested it.

Comment: please accept @Jongtae Lee's as a solution and not your comment.